# $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ continuous a.e. , is there a sequence of functions of finite discontinuity on $[a,b]$ converging uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, almost-everywhere

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be a function continuous almost everywhere , then does there exist a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ on $[a,b]$ , where each $f_n$ has at most finitely many discontinuity point  , such that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$  ?

Comment: Yes, $f_n=f$. :) Want to change the question?

Comment: @Jonas : Ah , yes , each $f_n$ should have at most finitely many discontinuity points

Answer (score 1):

If $f_n \colon [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of functions that are continuous at $x_0 \in [a,b]$ and $f_n$ converge uniformly to $f \colon [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is also continuous at $x_0$. Thus, if the set of discontinuities of $f$ is not countable, you can't approach $f$ uniformly by a sequence of functions with finitely many discontinuity points.

Comment: hmm , true indeed , I failed to notice that . So then can we always find such a sequence when $f$ has countably many discontinuity points ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Do you want to approximate $f$ with functions that have finitely many discontinuity points or with functions that are piecewise continuous?

Comment: by functions that have finitely many discontinuity points ...

Comment: If you take $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)}$ on $[0,1]$ then $f$ has countably many discontinuity points but you can't approximate $f$ uniformly with a function $g$ that has finitely many continuity points because $g$ must be bounded on an interval $(0,\delta)$ for sufficiently small $\delta$ while $f$ is unbounded on such an interval.